# Debugging MapReduce Hadoop in local mode in eclipse. Failed to connect remote VM

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to hadoop and I am trying to debug MapReduce Hadoop in local mode in Eclipse in Virtualbox Ubuntu following these articles: [Debug Custom Java hadoop code in local environment](http://understandbigdata.wordpress.com/tag/debug/) and [Hadoop MapReduce Debugging in Local Setup](http://amnigos.com/post/44631353593/how-to-guide-hadoop-mapreduce-debugging-in-lo)

In hadoop-env.sh I put the text

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8008"
```

I tried to run Eclipse from command line

```
eclipse -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8008
```

I also changed from `hdfs` to `file:///` in `core-site.xml` in hadoop configurations

```
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>file:///localhost:8020</value>
```

I checked the port 8080. Seems like it works okay:

```
netstat -atn | grep 8080`
```

says `tcp6 8080 LISTEN`

`http://localhost:8080` opens in browser and says `Required param job, map and reduce`

still everything is useless as when I try to set debug configuration with the port 8080 in Eclipse it breaks “failed to connect remote vm”.

Can anyone suggest a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't the way to run eclipse as a debugger.

Run eclipse without any command line options and setup a debug configuration for a remote java application that connects to 8008.

[EDIT]

I also think your hadoop debug options are wrong. I use:

-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8008,server=y,suspend=n

Comment: -agentlib is the same as -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp both together. Debugger doesn't work either run it without any commmand line options or with them. =( I try to set a debug configuration for a remote java applications with connection to 8008 when it says me that it can't connect remote VM